# change whole background color while clicking button in amx

Tags: javascript, css, jdeveloper, oracle-maf

In AMX page I have 2 commandButtons. If I click first command button, I want to change one background color for whole page. If I click second one, want to apply some other different background color. I am trying to insert javascript to doing this. But its not working. Please help me how can I do this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<amx:view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:amx="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/mf/amx"
          xmlns:dvtm="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/mf/amx/dvt">
    <amx:panelPage id="pp1">
        <amx:facet name="header">
            <amx:outputText value="Home" id="ot1"/>
        </amx:facet>
         <amx:commandButton text="Red" id="red" styleClass="blue-background">
            <amx:validationBehavior id="abc"/>
        </amx:commandButton>
        <amx:outputText value="Color" id="color"/>        
        <amx:commandButton text="Green" id="green" styleClass="green-background"/>       
    </amx:panelPage>
</amx:view>
```

The above code is my AMX page code. And my javascript code is,

```
$(function(){
     $("#red").on("click", function(){
        alert("clicked");        
     });
         $("#green").on("click", function(){
        alert("clicked second....");         
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea of AMX but this is how we do in javascript:

```
document.getElementById('green').onclick=function(){
            document.body.style.background='green';
                }
document.getElementById('red').onclick=function(){
        document.body.style.background='red';
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, Even that alert also not printing.  Its not calling jquery or javascript method. How to call commandButton Id inside javascript?

Comment: There is no HTML. In AMX itself I want to call javascript. Instead of HTML we are using AMX.

Comment: This one is also not working. Its not taking that id. In AMX page how can I do this?

Comment: Thank you so much ankit-chaudhary. In javascript it is already working. My question how to call AMX commandButton id inside javascript.

Comment: Hi Sathish , Did you try liike this? 
Just add an action listener to the command button , in that method just add the codes to invoke a javaScript method

Comment: I tried invoking a javascript function through an action listener on the button without success. I am not sure if I am doing something wrong I tried actionListener="#{hide}" and actionListener="#{this.hide}" and actionListener="#{hide()}" but none of them seemed to activate my function.